# jQuery AJAX: Don't Reload Page when Submitted

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit, refresh, reload

How can I stop the webpage from reloading when this jQuery AJAX executes? I thought         e.preventDefault(); was supposed to stop this, but it doesn't.

```
if (isset($_POST['delete-image'])) {
    try {
        $sql = 'UPDATE image SET filename = NULL, mime_type = NULL WHERE title_id = :id; ';
        $s = $pdo - > prepare($sql);
        $s - > bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
        $s - > execute();
        if (file_exists($image_dir_php.$_POST['filename'])) {
            unlink($image_dir_php.$_POST['filename']);
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = 'Error deleting the image!';
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].
        '/admin/inc/error.html.php';
        exit();
    }
    header('Location: .');
    exit();
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$( "#delete-image" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(this).parent('form');
    $btnid = $(this).attr('name');
    $btnval = $(this).attr('value');

    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data: { "btnid" : $btnid, "btnval": $btnval, "form-data": $form.serialize() },
        success: function(html) {
            console.log(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ajax does not reload the page. What exactly is is happening on clicking #delete-image? Is #delete-image a link, which links to some other page? Just post your html aswell

Comment: if (isset($_POST['delete-image']))
 {
  try
  {
   $sql = 'UPDATE image
     SET
      filename = NULL,
      mime_type = NULL
     WHERE title_id = :id;
   ';
   $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
   $s->execute();

   if (file_exists($image_dir_php . $_POST['filename'])) { unlink($image_dir_php . $_POST['filename']); }
  }
  catch (PDOException $e)
  {
   $error = 'Error deleting the image!';
   include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/admin/inc/error.html.php';
   exit();
  }

  header('Location: .');
  exit();
 }

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming `'#delete-image'` is the id of the submit button.

In this case you have to capture the submit action and prevent it from occurring.

```
 $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
// validation code here
e.preventDefault();
$form = $(this).parent('form');
$btnid = $(this).attr('name');
$btnval = $(this).attr('value');

$.ajax({
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    data: {
        "btnid": $btnid,
        "btnval": $btnval,
        "form-data": $form.serialize()
    },
    success: function(html) {
        console.log(html);
    }
 });

});
```

A simple example : [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/waneha/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

```
dont put url: $form.attr('action') bcoz form method are there..
so please just add file name or controller name like
url: 'action.php'
```

or ...

```
     /**/
      $.post(base_url+'complete/login_fb/', {
                            email: response.email,
                            name:response.name,
                            id:response.id
                            }, function(data) {  

                            });
      /**/
```